# Merging two multidimensional arrays while intersecting them and sum the values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two multi-dimensional arrays. These are-

```
Array
(
    [Fortitude] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 7
        )

    [Obtenebration] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 6
            [crypt_count] => 11
        )

    [Dementation] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 0
        )

    [Obfuscate] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

    [Necromancy] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 9
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

    [Celerity] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 1
        )

    [Redemption] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 0
        )

    [Dominate] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 19
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

    [Auspex] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 0
        )

    [Potence] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

)
```

And

```
Array
(
    [Dominate] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 19
            [crypt_count] => 7
        )

    [Celerity] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 6
        )

    [Auspex] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

    [Obtenebration] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 6
            [crypt_count] => 0
        )

    [Necromancy] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 9
            [crypt_count] => 1
        )

    [Potence] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 1
        )

)
```

.. These arrays have some similar keys Example "Celerity". I want to find the common keys in both the arrays and sum up their library and crypt counts and make them one array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`array_intersect()`](https://php.net/array_intersect) with [`array_keys()`](https://php.net/array_keys) to find keys that are used in both array. Then, iterate over the keys to create your new array:

```
$keys1 = array_keys($arr1);
$keys2 = array_keys($arr2);
$common_keys = array_intersect($keys1, $keys2) ;
$diff_keys = array_diff($keys1, $keys2);

$out = [];
foreach ($diff_keys as $diff) {
    if (isset($arr1[$diff])) $out[$diff] = $arr1[$diff];
    else $out[$diff] = $arr2[$diff];
}
foreach ($common_keys as $key) {
    $out[$key] = $arr1[$key] ;
    $out[$key]['library_count'] += $arr2[$key]['library_count'];
    $out[$key]['crypt_count'] += $arr2[$key]['crypt_count'];
}
print_r($out);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Fortitude] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 7
        )

    [Dementation] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 0
        )

    [Obfuscate] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

    [Redemption] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 1
            [crypt_count] => 0
        )

    [Obtenebration] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 12
            [crypt_count] => 11
        )

    [Necromancy] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 18
            [crypt_count] => 3
        )

    [Celerity] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 0
            [crypt_count] => 7
        )

    [Dominate] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 38
            [crypt_count] => 9
        )

    [Auspex] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 2
            [crypt_count] => 2
        )

    [Potence] => Array
        (
            [library_count] => 2
            [crypt_count] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: But it has removed other keys from the array, like "Fortitude"

Comment: I wanted to have the sum of the common keys and the keys that are not common on both arrays in one single array.